# ¿Cómo se implementa quicksort en una lista doblemente ligada?

Tags: c++, quicksort

¿Alguien podría decirme qué es lo que está mal en el código? Se supone que debería ordenarlos, pero en su lugar los deja igual, no cambia nada.
El nodo h es la cabecera y el t es la cola. He elegido el pivote como el primer elemento. EL algoritmo debería recorrer la lista sin problema, porque no tengo ningún problema a la hora de apilar o encolar, así que el problema radica aquí, en alguna parte.

```
//El lenguaje es c++
void lista::quicksort(nodo *h, nodo *t){
    nodo *piv, *p, *q, *aux;
    if(h != t){    //Comprobamos que haya más de un elemento
        piv = h;   //El pivote será el primer elemento
        p = piv->siguiente;    //Comenzamos a recorrer después del pivote
        cout << piv->dato << endl; //Pruba para ver cuál es el pivote
        q = t;    //Recorremos desde el último elemento
        //Se supone que quicksort comienza aquí
        while(p != q){
            while(q->dato > piv->dato && q != p){
                q = q->anterior;
            }
            while(p->dato < piv->dato && q != p){
                p = p->siguiente;
            }
            if(p != q){ //Intercambiamos los datos
                if(q == t){
                    t = p;
                }
                aux->dato = p->dato;
                p->dato = q->dato;
                q->dato = aux->dato;
                //Se supone que con el funcionamiento normal aquí se vuelven 
                //a recorrer los elementos, pero si hago eso, el programa se 
                //cierra
            }
        }
        //Recursividad

        if(piv!= h){
            quicksort(h, piv->anterior);
        }
        if(piv->siguiente!=NULL){
            quicksort(piv->siguiente, t);
        }

    }
}
```

Hasta ahora sólo consigo que el programa deje los números igual o que se cierre, y no entiendo la razón, si alguien pudiera decirme qué es lo que está mal o cómo se debe implementar de manera correcta, sería de mucha ayuda. Gracias de antemano.